# Find all Images in WordPress Table

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress

Is there a mysql query that can pull all of the images out of a table? Haven't had any luck finding a solution. Thanks

e. from a wordpress site

The images are all in the wp_posts table

In my wp_posts table all of the images are mixed in with other data. I would like to get all of the images out of this table to store on my hard drive

Comment: need a little more info about the table structure or what exactly you're trying to get.

Comment: You show me the table, I'll show you the query.

Comment: This isn't a game of [twenty questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty_Questions) - you actually need to tell us the necessary information (i.e.: database table schema(s)) up-front.

Comment: so what you want is a way to look at the post text and find all <img src=... tags then pull the image urls?

Comment: +1 for twenty questions :) I have the feeling that he actually means a page, not a database table.

Comment: No I really actually want to pull all the images out of my wp_posts table.

Comment: Images aren't stored like that in WordPress as far as I'm aware. (i.e.: You'll need to parse the data for each post and attempt to extract the image(s) used within.) What are you *really* trying to achieve? (i.e.: Do you want the paths of the images, or ?)

Comment: @Davey do you mean image references inside the HTML?

Comment: In my wp_posts table all of the images are mixed in with other data. I would like to get all of the images out of this table to store on my hard drive.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All records from a table

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
```

From a specific table

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
```

Based on [Wordpress Database ERD](http://codex.wordpress.org/File:WP3.0-ERD.png), to get attachments, this should be close

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type='attachment' and post_status='inherit'
```

This will give you the attachments as well as the parent post it related to, if you need some sort of context

```
SELECT 
  posts.ID,
  posts.post_title AS title,
  posts.post_content AS content,
  files.meta_value AS filepath
FROM
  wp_posts posts
  INNER JOIN wp_posts attachments ON posts.ID = attachments.post_parent
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta files ON attachments.ID = files.post_id
WHERE files.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
```

If I am not mistaken, the `filepath` gives you a link to a disk location where the image files are actually stored.  If that is all you want, just browse to it (or ftp if remote) and grab all files from there.

Comment: WordPress has an ERD? I didn't know that! +1

Comment: As of this writing, Wordpress 4.6-alpha-37598 to be specific, File URL is saved in ``guid`` field. Not sure though with post-based attachments/media.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with wordpress but I once had to do a similar thing and solved it via regular expressions.

I do not know a way of doing this directly in the query. I filtered the html code with regular expressions so as to obtain only the img-tags parts. I had to query all posts and then filter them.

I'm assuming you are looking to extract the <img /> tags from the posts?

Otherwise you should provide more info as middaparka already commented.